# Spark SQL: Repartition by column Exception "REPARTITION Hint expects a partition number as parameter"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to repartition a table on a specific column (keeping the default number of partitions), cache it and use it for a number of subsequent joins with other tables. According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#coalesce-hints-for-sql-queries) the syntax should be:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW V24 AS SELECT /*+ REPARTITION(c) */ * FROM t
```

But I am getting the exception "REPARTITION Hint expects a partition number as parameter". I also tried REPARTITION('c'), REPARTITION("c") and REPARTITION(col("c")), but nothing seems to work.

I am usign Spark 2.4.3.

Comment: I think using column as parameter is introduced in Spark 3

Comment: Well, I just realized that the documentation is about Spark 3. So I guess there is no way to achieve this in Spark 2